# How to get rid of the launch bar of eclipse by default?

Tags: eclipse

In the eclipse, I can get rid of the Launch bar by going to Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Launch Bar and unchecking it.
But when I create a new workspace, the launch bar is shown again, so I hope to find a way to get rid of the launch bar by default when I create a new workspace.

Comment: There are many ways for this. The easiest way in your case is probably to uninstall it: in _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_ tab _Installed Software_ selecting the _Launch Bar_ and hitting the button _Uninstall..._